# Confused about bash arithmetic comparison

Tags: bash

I've seen other answers about bash integer checks and comparisons, however the results I'm getting are very confusing to me.
Suppose I have this script:

```
if [[ $1 -eq $1 ]] ;then
  echo "number"
else
  echo "not number"
fi

if (( $1 >= 0 )) ;then
  echo "number"
else
  echo "not number"
fi
```

If I pass a string for parameter one , I get back "number".

Comment: Double square brackets is an expansion for regular expression functionality in bash. Try with `if [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] ;then` . Also double parenthesis are for arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Kadir: Not exactly. `[[` are prefered to `[` in bash.

Comment: value can be a string `abc` , `a` or number `123` `1`

Comment: It appears that if if I use only `[` the comparison properly detects if I pass a string or number.

Comment: @ivan-v Because if you use `[` , Bash expects an integer expression. Try with debugging it using `set -x` at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 2):

That's because string is understood as a variable whose value is 0, and `0 >= 0` is true. Try with `>` (but it will report 0 as `not number` - but it already misclassifies all negative integers).

Cf:

```
a=1
b=a
x=b
(( x > 0 )) && echo 1
a=0
(( x > 0 )) || echo 0
```

or even

```
$ a=x
$ x=a
$ (( x > 0 ))
bash: ((: a: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "a")
```

Bash tries hard to resolve the variable:

```
(
    for l in a{1..1023} ; do
        printf "$l\n$l="
    done
    echo 1
    echo '((a1>0))'
) | tail -n+2 | bash
```